# Can't get to the code of express server computer that looks like a big cmd

Tags: node.js, windows, express, server, command-line

For reference, I am not that great with servers. At my job we have a computer that is just a dedicated express server I believe. I want to be able to get on to it and edit the code directly, but when I attach it to a monitor this is what shows up:

https://ibb.co/j8vCrL5

It looks like just a large command prompt with no options to minimize or exit that is running the express server. If I press the windows button, nothing happens. If I press F11, it just types F11 in the line. If I type ipconfig /all and press enter, it just adds "ipconfig /all" to the line above.

My question is, how can I get to the code of this express server from here? Our IT guy left a few months ago so we are not sure how to move on.

Comment: You can use `find . -name "package.json"` may check where the express project exist. It could not be the best way, but can help you locate all the projects based on npm.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara no commands do anything, they just log in the line above

Comment: Relatively safe first step (i.e. with little risk of shutting down the currently running process, which is possibly mission critical on this server:) )  is to try and login in separate session. Try CTRL + ALT + F1 (or F2, F3...F12) to switch between consoles.  Chances are, under F6 or up you will have a regular desktop, or at least a login prompt.

Comment: @JockX thank you for that, every FX besides F1 switches to a different cmd that is an ubuntu login. Now this question is how to get to the code from here. I have never used ubuntu before.

Comment: There is just too little information for anyone to be able to solve this with you. Do you know the username and password to the machine? Do you know the directory in which the code is stored? Is it safe for you to stop the running process or restart the box? You could assume someone is logged in the terminal from the screenshot, so you could do the editing there, but for this you'd need to stop the running process there? Do you know how to restart it when done editing? At this point this is a https://serverfault.com/ question